# Exponential of Brownian motion on Lie algebra?

Tags: stochastic-processes, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

Let $G \subset GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ be a compact Lie group. Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be its Lie algebra, with inner product given by $\operatorname{tr} (A A^t)$. Isometrically identify $\mathfrak{g} \subset M_n(\mathbb{R})$ with $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $B(t)$ be the usual Brownian motion on $\mathfrak{g}$ under this identification. Using $ \exp : \mathfrak{g} \to G$, we can get a stochastic process, $\exp (B(t))$ on $G$, which looks reasonably like a Brownian motion starting at the identity matrix.

On the other hand, I am assured that for every Riemannian manifold, the Laplacian (somehow) produces a Brownian motion. I am intimidated by this construction (not having any background in Stochastic differential equations yet). If the general Brownian motion (for $G$ with the induced metric from the embedding) was the same as the one in my first paragraph then I would be very satisfied with that little bit of understanding.

Are they the same?

(Generally there is a geodesic exponential map for Riemannian manifolds, and I guess one could pose the same question. The metric above is bi-invariant, so my memory is that they agree. I'll stick to asking for this case of Lie groups because there is a "better chance" that it is true. However, I'm also interested in answers or comments about this interpretation.)

Edit:I guess there is no particular reason for them to be the same... lot's of things look like Brownian motion, but aren't (Brownian bridges, conditioning on being near a continuous function using Levy's forgery theorem, etc.). I guess I should just learn the accepted definition.

Comment: No they are not the same. Even in the commutative case they may not be the same as there could be the subtraction of a drift which is produced by the second order cancellations from the hessian induced by the metric. In the noncommutative case there is no hope of them coinciding (the curvature naturally induces nonlinearity into the situation).